# My pc keeps freezing and ive tried everything

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash, troubleshooting

my pc freezes every 1-4 hours and the only way to fix it is to restart it with the button on my pc case. but when it boots back up it freezes again and i have to restart it again and it finally works for like 1 hour. ive checked the event viewer and it doesnt show anything that would cause a crash. i slightly overclocked the cpu, ram and, gpu but i reset it back to stock clocks like 2 months and the freezing started like 1 month ago. it also seems to crash the second my blender render finishes and when i ctrl+alt+del out of a game. its not a software problem because ive reset windows 5 times and ive even tried linux and it still crashes. ive also ran memtest86 for 2 tries and there were no errors so if you know anything plz help

my specs are:

amd ryzen 5 3400g

evga gtx 960 4gb gddr5

xpg ax4u3200038g12a-dt60 ram

samsung 860 qvo 1tb ssd

my log files are https://www.mediafire.com/file/ldwy8k3xlyyyvux/logs.zip/file

i wrote this post in 5 minutes so its bad
plz help me fix my pc i cant play osu :(

Comment: You've tagged the post with "bsod", what error code gets displayed there?

Comment: I had bad experience with memtestx86 in the past. 

It is better to remove one memory module at a time and observe if the issue happens again. If the system runs as expected, you've found the bad module.

Answer (score 1):

> my pc freezes every 1-4 hours and the only way to fix it is to restart
> it with the button on my pc case...... ive also ran memtest86 for 2
> tries and there were no errors.
>
> .... ive reset windows 5 times and ive even tried linux and it still
> crashes.

First look in Windows Reliability Monitor for errors (Control Panel, Security and Maintenance). This will show both software and hardware errors.

Then get the Manufacturer's or main part manufacturers and test all of:   Drive (SSD Samsung Magician), Motherboard, memory, CPU and GPU.  Do all the hardware tests you can as it appears to be a hardware issue.

You can also consider taking it to a local computer shop for diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your CPU temperatures.  Your heatsink/fan and/or etc could be clogged with dust.  You need to open the case and clean out ALL the dust with the power off.
2. Next check that your power supply is providing voltage that are + or - 5% of the stated voltage.  3v,5v, or 12v.

Report your findings.